# Bash script to process files using multiple processes

Tags: bash, multiple-instances

Most batch file processing Bash scripts could be sped up by spawning multiple processes to utilize all the cores. I want to make a script that will process a bunch of files, dividing the number of files to process equally among processes. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to launch subprocesses in parallel. Has similar syntax as xargs. From [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html):

> To compress all html files using gzip run:
>
> `find . -name '*.html' | parallel gzip --best`

Comment: GNU Parallel doesn't seem to come pre-installed on many Unix systems (including OS X and Ubuntu Server), but it is a lot nicer than the other method if you have the option of installing it. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the nicest way to do it, but here's what I came up with.

Usage: `batch.sh [number of processes to use]`

batch.sh:

```
end=$(( $1 - 1 ))
for i in `seq 0 $end`;
        do
            echo Spawning helper $i of $end
            ./helper.sh $i $1 &
        done
```

helper.sh:

```
n=$1
for file in ./*; do
   # Your code here v
   echo Processing file: $file
   # ^
   n=$((n+1))
   n=$((n%$2))
done
```

This spawns n processes that each process a file then skip (n - 1) files. Process (i mod n) processes the ith file.